# How do i create a unicode filename in linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unicode, utf-8

I heard fopen supports UTF8 but i dont know how to convert an array of shorts to utf8

How do i create a file with unicode letters in it? I prefer to use only built in libraries (no boost which is not installed on the linux box). I do need to use fopen but its pretty simple to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fopen(3)` supports any valid byte sequence; the encoding is unimportant. Use `nl_langinfo(3)` with `CODESET` to get what charset you should use for the encoding, and libiconv or icu for the actual encoding.

Comment: +1, but you forget the need to call setlocale so that nl_langinfo(3) returns the correct result.